# ajax request does not run first before postback in linkbutton asp

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to run an insert statement using a button in my application. The thing is it is working except that I noticed that whenever I try to click the button, I noticed it would run the Page_Load first before it could run the ajax statement.

what should I do to allow the ajax statement work first before the Page_Load?

This is my button:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="uoCheckBoxTagtoVehicle" Text="Tag" Width="50px" Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TaggedActive")) == 0 ? true : false %>'  OnClick='<%# "TagChanged(this, "+ Eval("colIdBigint") +", "+ Eval("colTravelReqIDInt") +", \""+ Eval("RecordLocator") +"\", "+ Eval("SeafarerIdInt") +", "+ Eval("colVehicleVendorIDInt") +", \""+ Eval("colSFStatus")+ "\" , "+ Eval("colVehicleVendorIDInt")+")" %>' runat="server" />
```

and this is my ajax request inside my function(which is working):

```
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/PageMethods.aspx/TagtoVehicle")%>",
        data: "{'colIDBigint': '" + IDBigInt + "', 'colTravelReqIDInt': '" + TravelReq +
        "', 'colRecordLocatorVarchar': '" + RecordLoc + "', 'colSeafarerIdInt': '" + SeafarerId + "', 'colOnOff': '" + colSFStatus + "', 'colPortAgentVendorIDInt': '" + Vehiclevendor + "', 'colSFStatus': '" + onoff + "', 'UserId': '" + userId +  "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        } ,
        error: function(objXMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declare `OnClick` event in your LinkButton, OnClick event execute on server side so it is obvious it will call page load method.

You should use `OnClientClick` event instead of `OnClick`. it allow to execute javascript function.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="uoCheckBoxTagtoVehicle" Text="Tag" Width="50px" Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TaggedActive")) == 0 ? true : false %>' OnClientClick="callMyFuction" runat="server" />
```

On javascript side

```
function callMyFuction(){
//you can call your ajax request here.
}
```